# How to not Include in Wildcard?

Tags: microsoft-word, wildcards

I am using the wildcard feature option on word to replace a specific contain on my word document.

My goal is to remove everything on my 500 pages that are between Reception and Organization2.

I used this search string: Reception:*Organization2:
That works but I don't want to select Organization2: do you know how to select until but not include it ?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to replace the string with `Organization2`?

You can edit the format of the output, so it'll match the headlines.

Comment: I think that you'll also want to leave an empty line in-between the paragraph with the correct formatting; in that case, I'd run "Replace" with target string '\nasd\nOrganization2', then run another "Replace" to change 'asd' into '' ( nothing ) with the desired format for regular text.

Comment: By using Reception:*Organization2: I can select what I desire to remove.
WHen I remove it, that remove also Organization2:
Which I don't want to remove.
What I would like is just to select everything between Reception: until the end of Recepetion2:

I use < > [!] nothing works...

How  can we select Until ?

Comment: @killua Instead of answering and asking new questions in comments, you should [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1776255/edit) your original question to add new info, clarifications etc. That way it stays up-to-date and gets more focused, and everything relevant is readily. The comment section isn't intended for discussions, but for others to ask for clarifications, suggest remedies that might work but don't qualify as a full answer etc. That's why the open comment space is a bit restricted. Repeating in comments what's already in the question isn't really helpful.

Comment: @killua Please re-read my answer. Instead of replacing with "nothing", replace with "\nOrganization2".

Comment: Adding: \n just adds an empty line ( which, I'm pretty sure you want )